# C Basic Programming, it doesnt print a value in for if else if algorithm

Tags: c

Just started learning programming a few days ago, so i hope you dont be so harsh on me.

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; i < 12; i++) {
    if ((i++ + 1) == 5)
        printf("%d\n", i);
    else 
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
            break;
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
            continue;
        else 
            printf("%d\n", i );
}
getch();
return 0;
```

It prints:

```
1
5
7
11
```

But in my opinion it should have printed:

```
1
3
5
7
11
```

when "i" is "3", shouldnt have this first "if" be right/positive/orsomething and printed 3 too? if the print is okay, may i ask why/how?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't print `3` -> `if (i % 3 == 0) continue;`.

Comment: It is a good idea to use braces.

Comment: Like _all_ problems in programming, you need to break things down into the smallest still-functional pieces you can in order to understand what you must do (or, in this case, what you have done). Practicing that will be immensely helpful for you in the long run.

Comment: 'Just started learning programming a few days ago' - OK,you should make your next move learning to use a debugger.  You should not write any more code until you have that skill:)

Comment: try to use debugger to understand what is going on

Comment: Thanks for the supportive comments! :)) i will learn debugging as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:

```
    if (i % 2 == 0) 
        break;
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
        continue;
    else 
        printf("%d\n", i );
```

When `i` is 3, the second condition `(i % 3 == 0)` evaluates to true, since 3 mod 3 is 0.  So it executes the `continue` statement.

Regarding this part:

```
if ((i++ + 1) == 5)
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

`i` will have been 2 prior to the `if` part being executed.  So it evaluates `((2 + 1) == 5)`, which is false.  The only time this will be true is when `i` is 4 prior to this statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i couldnt get it much :( when "i" becomes 3 coz of the increment in for loop, doesnt "i++ + 1 == 5" mean 3+1+1 = 5? And I thought when this first if condition was true, "i % 3 == 0" wasnt going to get checked, am I wrong?

Comment: @Sezar No, you put an extra term in there.  The postincrement operator means the expression takes the old value of the variable, then the variable is incremented.  So if `i` starts out as 3, `i++` evaluates to 3, with a side effect of `i` being incremented to 4 afterward.  Had you done `++i`, then you'd get the behavior you described.  But even if you did, it wouldn't change your program's output.  Because you're incrementing twice each time through the loop, `i` is always even before that `if` block executes.

Comment: Now I get it completely! I appreciate for the help :)